# NTFS Compression very slow when enabled on individual folders

Tags: ntfs, compression

I wanted to know if anyone had come across a problem with copying files to an SSD which is using NTFS compression. I enabled compression on all of the folders on a Crucial 1TB SSD to save some space. However, I found when copying files it was painfully slow, around 50MB/s or less, as apposed to the 400MB/s I was getting previously.

To test this, I created two folders, one with compression switched on and one with compression switched off. When copying a 40GB file (a Virual Box VM) to the uncompressed folder it copies at 400MB/s, when copying to the compressed folder it copies at around 30MB/s per second.

I have updated drivers etc. I'm not sure if it is because I turned on compression on folders individually.

Comment: What is your CPU?